# UIButton IB vs programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

When I make a custom UIButton with a background in interface builder, it gives me this default functionality of when i touch up inside, it sort of blacks out the image.
If I create the UIButton programmatically, like this:

```
    buttonPic = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 63)];
    [[buttonPic imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

[buttonPic setImage:[video pic] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

it doesn't behave like the one I created in IB at all. Nothing changes when I touch up inside.
Is there a settings in UIButton that I am missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must enable one of this two options:

```
buttonPic.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
buttonPic.reversesTitleShadowWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how to create a UIButton programatically.

```
//Specify the type of the button first. No need to use alloc-init for UIButton like other view objects.

UIButton *myBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 

// Give UIButtonTypeRoundedRect to get default Interface builder style button. 

myBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);
[self.view addSubview:myBtn];

 // Since the button type is custom, give an image to make it visible.
[myBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:normal];
[myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// These are some optional methods you may want to use.

myBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
[myBtn setTitle:@"my button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:normal];
[myBtn setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
```